# How to transform a data frame by grouping by an individual and checking if a feature exists from a list?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following issue. I have a data frame like this:

| ID | feature |
| --- | --- |
| Person_1 | 18 |
| Person_1 | 19 |
| Person_1 | 23 |
| Person_1 | 59 |
| Person_2 | 11 |
| Person_2 | 23 |
| Person_2 | 59 |
| Person_3 | 11 |
| Person_3 | 18 |
| Person_3 | 1001 |
| Person_3 | 1239 |
| Person_4 | 23 |
| Person_4 | 6531 |
| Person_4 | 19843 |
| Person_4 | 200012 |
| …… |  |
| Person_60 | …. |

Each feature is in a new row. I have a list of features that I could have:

| features |
| --- |
| 11 |
| 18 |
| 19 |
| 23 |
| 59 |
| 1001 |
| 1239 |
| 6531 |
| 19843 |
| 200012 |

I need the output to be like that:

|  | 11 | 18 | 19 | 23 | 59 | 1001 | 1239 | 6531 | 19843 | 200012 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Person_1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Person_2 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Person_3 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Person_4 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

When each person is in a row, their features are assigned based on the list of features.

I've tried something like this, but it's not even close.

```
for i in pd.DataFrame[~ df.duplicated(subset=['id'])]:
  for Feature in feature_list:
    if feature_list in df['feature'].unique():
      print('1')
    else:
      print('0')
```

I'm a bit lost. How to approach the problem could you help me with that?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a number of ways you could do this. Here's one way.

Stating with

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([
    ["Person_1", 1],
    ["Person_1", 2],
    ["Person_2", 1],
    ["Person_3", 3],
], columns=["ID", "feature"])
```

which looks like

```
         ID  feature
0  Person_1        1
1  Person_1        2
2  Person_2        1
3  Person_3        3
```

you should use a `groupby` and `unstack`:

```py
df = df.groupby(["ID", "feature"]).size().unstack(fill_value=0).reset_index()
```

which yields

```
feature        ID  1  2  3
0        Person_1  1  1  0
1        Person_2  1  0  0
2        Person_3  0  0  1
```